# mesos hadoop org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker not starting

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, mesos, mesosphere

I am following https://github.com/mesos/hadoop

```
On Linux:

$ MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY=/path/to/libmesos.so hadoop jobtracker
```

This gives an error of:

> DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute mapred command is
>   deprecated. Instead use the mapred command for it.
>
> Sorry, the jobtracker command is no longer supported. You may find
>   similar functionality with the "yarn" shell command. Usage: mapred
>   [--config confdir] COMMAND
>          where COMMAND is one of:   pipes                run a Pipes job   job                  manipulate MapReduce jobs   queue
>   get information regarding JobQueues   classpath            prints the
>   class path needed for running
>                          mapreduce subcommands   historyserver        run job history servers as a standalone daemon   distcp 
>    copy file or directories recursively   archive -archiveName
>   NAME -p  *  create a hadoop archive   hsadmin 
>   job history server admin interface
>
> Most commands print help when invoked w/o parameters.

While executing the downloaded hadoop binary yields:

```
~/hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.2.0 # MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/libmesos.so ./bin/hadoop jobtracker
Error: Could not find or load main class   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker
```

What am i missing?

CLASSPATH before execution:

```
root@mesos-master3 ~/hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.2.0 # MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/libmesos.so ./bin/hadoop jobtracker
/root/hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.2.0/bin-mapreduce1/../etc/hadoop:/usr/lib/tools.jar:/root/hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.2.0/bin-mapreduce1/../share/hadoop/mapreduce1/hadoop-core-2.5.0-mr1-cdh5.2.0.jar:/root/hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.2.0/bin-mapreduce1/../lib/*.jar:/root/hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.2.0/bin-mapreduce1/../lib/jsp-2.1/*.jar:/root/hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.2.0/bin-mapreduce1/../etc/hadoop:/root/hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/root/hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.2.0/share/hadoop/common/*:/root/hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs:/root/hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/root/hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/root/hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/root/hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/root/hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce:/root/hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/root/hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker
```

Answer (score 0):

Modern versions of Hadoop (2.4+) enable YARN/MapReduce2 by default, so the older MRv1 JobTracker/TaskTracker commands won't work out of the box. You'll either have to change your config to enable MRv1 (set `HADOOP_HOME` and `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` to point to the MR1 directories) or switch to YARN on Mesos via Myriad: https://github.com/mesos/myriad